# SQL Server : checking the validity of the date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get records with only valid date format (`YYYYMMDD`). I am using the following `where` condition. I was wondering is there any other way to do this?

```
    s.Date IS NOT NULL
    AND ISDATE(s.Date) = 1
    AND LEN(s.Date) > 4
    AND s.Date < GETDATE())
```

Comment: Is your date data stored as "DateTime", "Date" or "Varchar"?

Comment: Using the correct datatype in the first place would avoid this travesty. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: Can you clear up some confusion. Do you want only records that CAN be converted to YYYYMMDD? OR do you want only those records that are ALREADY in the format YYYYMMDD?

Comment: Mittal, it is stored as Varchar.

Comment: Edward, I wanted only those records that are already in the format YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 2):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or higher, you can use [TRY_CONVERT()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the `FORMAT()` function to achieve this.

```
SELECT s.Date 
...
FROM ...
WHERE 
        s.Date IS NOT NULL
    AND ISDATE(s.Date) = 1
    AND s.Date = FORMAT(s.Date, 'yyyymmdd');
```

But this may be rather slow, as it has to run the `FORMAT()` function for every record returned for each record that passed the other `WHERE` conditions.

But you can give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want *any* valid date format, then you can use:

```
where try_convert(varchar(255), s.date) is not null
```

If you specifically want YYYYMMDD, then you can do:

```
where try_convert(varchar(255), s.date, 112) is not null
```